# Cross-Library JSON Configuration in .NET Core

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, configuration, config

Let's say I have some projects, a library `Foo` and two projects `Bar` and `Baz`, which depend on `Foo`. `Foo` contains some configuration that will be shared between `Bar` and `Baz`, but `Bar` and `Baz` will also do some configuration that is different between them.

In `Foo`, I have a configuration file:

```json
/* /dev/Foo/fooConfig.json */
{
   "lorem": "ipsum",
   "dolor": "set"
}
```

and a method that does the initial configuration:

```cs
/* /dev/Foo/configuration.cs */
public static IConfigurationBuilder BuildBaseConfiguration()
{
   return new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddJsonFile("fooConfig.json")
}
```

Then in `Bar`, I have something similar:

```json
/* /dev/Bar/barConfig.json */
{
   "semper": "suspendisse"
}
```

```cs
/* /dev/Bar/Program.cs */
public static void main()
{
   BuildBaseConfiguration()
      .AddJsonFile("barConfig.json")
      .Build();
}
```

Normally, `Foo` is distributed as a NuGet package, but during development, I reference it locally by including the following `Bar.csproj`:

```xml
<Reference Include="Foo">
   <HintPath>../Foo/bin/Debug/net6.0/Foo.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I've made sure that `fooConfig.json` is being copied to the output directory, and that it is indeed appearing after successfully running a build.

However, after running `Bar`, I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'fooConfig.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was '/dev/Bar/bin/Debug/net6.0/fooConfig.json'.

It would seem that .NET Core is looking for the config file using a relative file path based on the working directory at runtime (`/dev/Bar/bin/Debug/net6.0`), rather than where the file is actually kept (`../Foo/bin/Debug/net6.0/fooConfig.json`).

How do I correct this behavior, so that .NET Core references the real location of `fooConfig.json`?

Answer (score 0):

By default `ConfigurationBuilder` is using `AppContext.BaseDirectory` ([see the source code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions/FileConfigurationExtensions.cs,46)) as root for the file search. You can try something like the following to override this behaviour:

```cs
// for development environment:
var compositeFileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(new[]
{
    new PhysicalFileProvider(AppContext.BaseDirectory),
    new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(SomeTypeFromFooDll).Assembly.Location))
});
var cfgBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetFileProvider(compositeFileProvider);
// ... rest of cfg setup
```

P.S.

Personally I think that library should not come with it's config files and I would refactor the code in such way that it exposes the settings type (with some default values) and it is up to the consuming project to handle those.

Comment: Yeah, as I've been reviewing things, it seems like the more appropriate course of action would be to re-factor these into enums or other types, something that will be naturally included in the dll.